# Unable to start Selenium Server on Windows

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-server

I am trying to start selenium server on my machine.

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/ 
Language Client Version
Java     2.53.0

When I try to run the Jar I get following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/col
lect/ImmutableMap$Builder
        at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher.(GridLauncher.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Immutable
Map$Builder
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more

I have latest java version on my machine.
It would be great if someone could help me on this.
Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Please indicate how you're running selenium and please include the full stack trace. Are you using the standalone server?  It includes the dependencies.

Comment: Yes I am using standalone server. Looks like there was some issue with the jar that I was using. I tried to download it again and everything worked fine.Thank you all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check you firfox version. if it is 47, os should be windows 10. try install firefox below 45 version. make sure java jar files should be configured in ide or netbeans.
Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few jars it seems. Add all jar from 'libs' folder of the Java Client folder to project.